# Can I specify the default for a SelectListItem in the .cshtml?

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, razor

I have a set of dropdown values defined in a global .cs file:

**mydropdowns.cs**

```
public class Foo_DropdownValues
{
    public static List<SelectListItem> NoYes { get; } = new List<SelectListItem>
    {
        new SelectListItem { Value = "false", Text = "No"},
        new SelectListItem { Value = "true", Text = "Yes" }
    };
    ...
```

I'm using these SelectLists in different places in my .cshtml web form:

**mypage.cshtml**

```
    <div class="form-group" id="PC_QU10_div">
        <label>@Foo_Questions.QU10</label>
        <select asp-for="Foo_Answers.QU10" asp-items="Foo_DropdownValues.NoYes"></select>
    </div>
    <div class="form-group" id="PC_QU20_div">
        <label>@Foo_Questions.QU20</label>
        <select asp-for="Foo_Answers.QU20" asp-items="Foo_DropdownValues.NoYes"></select>
        ...
```

I'd like to specify a default of "Yes" for the first item, and a default of "No" for the second?

Q: Is there any way for my to specify an explicit default in the .cshtml markup?  On a per-item basis?

My app is written in C# in .Net Core 3.1, if it matters.

Comment: If you set value of `Foo_Answers.QU20` from back end then that value will be selected in drop-down.

Comment: If you just have yes/no in a list, why not write them out manually and avoid worrying about the model? Or you could have two model properties, one with default yes and the other with default of no.

Comment: Besides, you could also try to use JS to modify the select option after the page has loaded completely. If you want to do it by using asp.net core tag helper, you should rewrite the select tag helper and check the select's name and provide addinational property to it. It will be more complex.

Comment: @Chetan Ranpariya: yours is the best solution so far.  If you wanted to make it an "answer", I'd be happy to "upvote" and "accept" it :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When a view has a model type specified, input controls for each of the properties of model object can be created using either the HTML Helper methods (@Html.TextBoxFor, @Html.CheckBoxFor, @Html.RadioButtonFor, @Html.DropdownListFor) etc. or using `asp-for` attributes in the input controls.

Both of these above mentioned ways, makes sure that the value entered/selected in the input control will be assigned to the model object properties when form is submitted and also the input controls are populated with the respective property values from the model object if the model object is being passed to the view from the server.

That's why, in this particular case, if the dropdown needs to have a specific value pre-selected (or by default selected), a value needs to be assigned to the dropdownlist. And it can be easily done by populating value in the property of the model object.

Consider example below:

Model class:

```
public class PersonData
{
    public string FirstName { get; set; }

    public string LastName { get; set; }

    public string Gender { get; set; }

    public bool IsMarried { get; set; }

    public bool IsLeftHanded { get; set; }
}
```

Static list of items for dropdownlist.

```
public static class StaticValues
{
    public static SelectListItem[] Genders
    {
        get
        {
            return new SelectListItem[]
            {
                new SelectListItem("Male", "Male"),
                new SelectListItem("Female", "Female")
            };
        }
    }

    public static SelectListItem[] YesNoItems
    {
        get
        {
            return new SelectListItem[]
            {
                new SelectListItem("Yes", "True"),
                new SelectListItem("No", "False")
            };
        }
    }
}
```

View Code:

```
@model PersonData;
@{
    ViewData["Title"] = "Person data";
}

<div>
    <label asp-for="FirstName">Firstname:</label>
    <input asp-for="FirstName"/>
</div>
<div>
    <label asp-for="LastName">Lastname:</label>
    <input asp-for="LastName" />
</div>

<div>
    <label asp-for="Gender">Firstname:</label>
    <select asp-for="Gender" asp-items="@StaticValues.Genders"></select>
</div>
<div>
    <label asp-for="IsMarried">Married:</label>
    <select asp-for="IsMarried" asp-items="@StaticValues.YesNoItems"></select>
</div>

<div>
    <label asp-for="IsLeftHanded">Left handed:</label>
    <select asp-for="IsLeftHanded" asp-items="@StaticValues.YesNoItems"></select>
</div>
```

In the following code from Controller Action method, model object is populated with a few properties with values assigned to them. And the model object is passed to the View.

```
public async Task<IActionResult> Index()
    {
        var personData = new PersonData();
        // This assignment should populate the text box with John value
        personData.FirstName = "John";
        // Gender dropdown should have Male pre-selected
        personData.Gender = "Male";

        // IsMarried dropwodn should have "Yes" pre-selected.
        personData.IsMarried = true;
        return View(personData);
    }
```

Following is the view rendered when application is run.

[image]

In a different use case, there can be a requirement where a specific value needs to be pre-selected by default when model property does not have value assigned to the property.

In such situations, specific SelectListItem should have `Selected` property set to true.

For example, in below list of SelectListItem **New York** has `true` passed as third argument in [constructor](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/microsoft.aspnetcore.mvc.rendering.selectlistitem?view=aspnetcore-5.0). That will mark that item as selected be-default in the dropdownlist.

```
public static SelectListItem[] OfficeLocations
{
        get
        {
            return new SelectListItem[]
            {
                new SelectListItem("London", "LON"),
                new SelectListItem("New York", "NY", true),
                new SelectListItem("Singapore", "SG")
            };
        }
}
```

Now I will add new property OfficeLocation to PersonData class as following.

public string OfficeLocation { get; set; }

And add following code to view.

```
<div>
    <label asp-for="OfficeLocation">Office location:</label>
    <select asp-for="OfficeLocation" asp-items="@StaticValues.OfficeLocations"></select>
</div>
```

Now if the model object does not have any value assigned to OfficeLocation property, the OfficeLocation dropdown will have **New York** selected by default.

The view will look as following.

[image]

I hope this will help you resolve your issue.

Answer (score 1):

There are 2 options that I know of that can work depending on requirements:

1.) Add a disabled default option directly in the mark-up

```
    <select ...>
        <option disabled value="">Choose an option</option>
    </select>
```

2.) Set the default selected value in your PageModel / Code behind before returning the view. If you want to continue to use a static reference for the common list, you can create a static method that takes a `bool selected` parameter instead of a readonly property:

```
var items = new List<SelectListItem>();
...
items.Insert(0, new SelectListItem("No", "No", selected: true));
//..insert other items
```

Comment: Thank you, but there are many problems with this approach. CONTEXT: 1) the whole point of "Foo_DropdownValues" was to define a set of "reusable pick lists". 2) the question was if there was any straightforward way I could specify a default for the pick-list directly in the .cshtml, the same place(s) where I'm using it.  3) The answer appears to be "No" (at least as far as the .cshtml).  4) But Chetan Ranpariya suggested a nice, simple alternative: specifying a value to the bound variable (before I return the view) should effectively make it the "default" when the web form is rendered :)

Comment: @paulsm4 - Ah I see, Chetan's suggestion is very simple. I wasn't aware that the control behaved in that way. Good to know

Comment: Please feel free to "upvote" Chetan's response :)